Calculating percentile over a sliding window in Power Query
I have a table with 5 columns, District (type text), Month Cumulative (Int64.Type), Measurement (type text), Value (type number) and Monthdate (type Date, 1/mm/yyyy).  The table is sorted on District then Measurement then Monthdate (desc).
What I need to do is this: I need a new column which holds, for any Monthdate within 36 months of the maximum (i.e. most recent) Monthdate, the 95th percentile of the Value column calculated over a sliding window of 36 months prior to that date - so for a Monthdate of 31/12/2023 I would want the 95th percentile of values from 1/1/2020 to 31/12/2023.  My thinking was that for each Monthdate within the last 36 months to use List.Generate, seeded with the appropriate [Index] and [Value] and iterate that 36 times, then to calculate the percentile on that list.
What I am trying, basically, is:
   #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"District", "Measurement", "MonthDate", "Index"}, {
        {"Percentile95", each
        let 
            ValueList = (x) => List.Generate(
            [a = x[Index], b = x[Index] + 36, c = x[Value]],
            each [a] <= [b],
            each [ a = [a] + 1, b = [b], c = x[Value]], 
            each [c]
            ),

            // Calculate the 95th percentile and round to 1 decimal place
            Percentile = if List.NonNullCount(ValueList) > 0
                            then Number.Round(List.Percentile(ValueList, 0.95), 1)
                            else null
        in
            Percentile,
        type nullable number
        }
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

The error I get is that "We cannot convert Function to List"
I think the approach might be ok but I just cannot get the syntax correct.  Any help much appreciated.
Many many thanks....



District
Measurement
Value
MonthDate
MonthCumulative
Index




District 1
Measure A
346
1/04/2024
76
0


District 1
Measure A
338
1/03/2024
75
1


District 1
Measure A
338
1/02/2024
74
2


District 1
Measure A
365
1/01/2024
73
3


District 1
Measure A
379
1/12/2023
72
4


District 1
Measure A
413
1/11/2023
71
5


District 1
Measure A
336
1/10/2023
70
6


District 1
Measure A
353
1/09/2023
69
7


District 1
Measure A
382
1/08/2023
68
8


District 1
Measure A
318
1/07/2023
67
9


District 1
Measure A
308
1/06/2023
66
10


District 1
Measure A
423
1/05/2023
65
11


District 1
Measure A
319
1/04/2023
64
12


District 1
Measure A
373
1/03/2023
63
13


District 1
Measure A
310
1/02/2023
62
14


District 1
Measure A
378
1/01/2023
61
15


District 1
Measure A
360
1/12/2022
60
16


District 1
Measure A
380
1/11/2022
59
17


District 1
Measure A
371
1/10/2022
58
18


District 1
Measure A
366
1/09/2022
57
19


District 1
Measure A
390
1/08/2022
56
20


District 1
Measure A
376
1/07/2022
55
21


District 1
Measure A
317
1/06/2022
54
22


District 1
Measure A
362
1/05/2022
53
23


District 1
Measure A
337
1/04/2022
52
24


District 1
Measure A
287
1/03/2022
51
25


District 1
Measure A
333
1/02/2022
50
26


District 1
Measure A
395
1/01/2022
49
27


District 1
Measure A
400
1/12/2021
48
28


District 1
Measure A
376
1/11/2021
47
29


District 1
Measure A
318
1/10/2021
46
30


District 1
Measure A
263
1/09/2021
45
31


District 1
Measure A
332
1/08/2021
44
32


District 1
Measure A
328
1/07/2021
43
33


District 1
Measure A
405
1/06/2021
42
34


District 1
Measure A
426
1/05/2021
41
35


District 1
Measure A
352
1/04/2021
40
36


District 1
Measure A
328
1/03/2021
39
37


District 1
Measure A
320
1/02/2021
38
38


District 1
Measure A
292
1/01/2021
37
39


District 1
Measure A
260
1/12/2020
36
40


District 1
Measure A
248
1/11/2020
35
41


District 1
Measure A
265
1/10/2020
34
42


District 1
Measure A
248
1/09/2020
33
43


District 1
Measure A
223
1/08/2020
32
44


District 1
Measure A
197
1/07/2020
31
45


District 1
Measure A
219
1/06/2020
30
46


District 1
Measure A
186
1/05/2020
29
47


District 1
Measure A
129
1/04/2020
28
48


District 1
Measure A
184
1/03/2020
27
49


District 1
Measure A
182
1/02/2020
26
50


District 1
Measure A
177
1/01/2020
25
51


District 1
Measure A
209
1/12/2019
24
52


District 1
Measure A
173
1/11/2019
23
53


District 1
Measure A
181
1/10/2019
22
54


District 1
Measure A
153
1/09/2019
21
55


District 1
Measure A
159
1/08/2019
20
56


District 1
Measure A
173
1/07/2019
19
57


District 1
Measure A
157
1/06/2019
18
58


District 1
Measure A
156
1/05/2019
17
59


District 1
Measure A
134
1/04/2019
16
60


District 1
Measure A
158
1/03/2019
15
61


District 1
Measure A
160
1/02/2019
14
62


District 1
Measure A
184
1/01/2019
13
63


District 1
Measure A
217
1/12/2018
12
64


District 1
Measure A
122
1/11/2018
11
65


District 1
Measure A
193
1/10/2018
10
66


District 1
Measure A
160
1/09/2018
9
67


District 1
Measure A
173
1/08/2018
8
68


District 1
Measure A
162
1/07/2018
7
69


District 1
Measure A
154
1/06/2018
6
70


District 1
Measure A
166
1/05/2018
5
71


District 1
Measure A
159
1/04/2018
4
72


District 1
Measure A
162
1/03/2018
3
73


District 1
Measure A
174
1/02/2018
2
74


District 1
Measure A
168
1/01/2018
1
75


District 1
Measure B
1685
1/04/2024
76
76


District 1
Measure B
1587
1/03/2024
75
77


District 1
Measure B
1283
1/02/2024
74
78


District 1
Measure B
1532
1/01/2024
73
79


District 1
Measure B
1724
1/12/2023
72
80


District 1
Measure B
1237
1/11/2023
71
81


District 1
Measure B
1383
1/10/2023
70
82


District 1
Measure B
1410
1/09/2023
69
83


District 1
Measure B
1383
1/08/2023
68
84


District 1
Measure B
1386
1/07/2023
67
85


District 1
Measure B
1280
1/06/2023
66
86


District 1
Measure B
1327
1/05/2023
65
87


District 1
Measure B
1311
1/04/2023
64
88


District 1
Measure B
1468
1/03/2023
63
89


District 1
Measure B
1140
1/02/2023
62
90


District 1
Measure B
1317
1/01/2023
61
91


District 1
Measure B
1328
1/12/2022
60
92


District 1
Measure B
1363
1/11/2022
59
93


District 1
Measure B
1218
1/10/2022
58
94


District 1
Measure B
1098
1/09/2022
57
95


District 1
Measure B
1241
1/08/2022
56
96


District 1
Measure B
1142
1/07/2022
55
97


District 1
Measure B
1065
1/06/2022
54
98


District 1
Measure B
1151
1/05/2022
53
99


District 1
Measure B
1008
1/04/2022
52
100


District 1
Measure B
1153
1/03/2022
51
101


District 1
Measure B
992
1/02/2022
50
102


District 1
Measure B
1074
1/01/2022
49
103


District 1
Measure B
928
1/12/2021
48
104


District 1
Measure B
827
1/11/2021
47
105


District 1
Measure B
765
1/10/2021
46
106


District 1
Measure B
652
1/09/2021
45
107


District 1
Measure B
1010
1/08/2021
44
108


District 1
Measure B
1027
1/07/2021
43
109


District 1
Measure B
1066
1/06/2021
42
110


District 1
Measure B
1116
1/05/2021
41
111


District 1
Measure B
960
1/04/2021
40
112


District 1
Measure B
960
1/03/2021
39
113


District 1
Measure B
694
1/02/2021
38
114


District 1
Measure B
985
1/01/2021
37
115


District 1
Measure B
873
1/12/2020
36
116


District 1
Measure B
893
1/11/2020
35
117


District 1
Measure B
776
1/10/2020
34
118


District 1
Measure B
762
1/09/2020
33
119


District 1
Measure B
609
1/08/2020
32
120


District 1
Measure B
759
1/07/2020
31
121


District 1
Measure B
628
1/06/2020
30
122


District 1
Measure B
364
1/05/2020
29
123


District 1
Measure B
227
1/04/2020
28
124


District 1
Measure B
665
1/03/2020
27
125


District 1
Measure B
692
1/02/2020
26
126


District 1
Measure B
691
1/01/2020
25
127


District 1
Measure B
751
1/12/2019
24
128


District 1
Measure B
582
1/11/2019
23
129


District 1
Measure B
625
1/10/2019
22
130


District 1
Measure B
580
1/09/2019
21
131


District 1
Measure B
594
1/08/2019
20
132


District 1
Measure B
571
1/07/2019
19
133


District 1
Measure B
605
1/06/2019
18
134


District 1
Measure B
525
1/05/2019
17
135


District 1
Measure B
566
1/04/2019
16
136


District 1
Measure B
537
1/03/2019
15
137


District 1
Measure B
523
1/02/2019
14
138


District 1
Measure B
706
1/01/2019
13
139


District 1
Measure B
532
1/12/2018
12
140


District 1
Measure B
557
1/11/2018
11
141


District 1
Measure B
505
1/10/2018
10
142


District 1
Measure B
506
1/09/2018
9
143


District 1
Measure B
564
1/08/2018
8
144


District 1
Measure B
587
1/07/2018
7
145


District 1
Measure B
517
1/06/2018
6
146


District 1
Measure B
545
1/05/2018
5
147


District 1
Measure B
453
1/04/2018
4
148


District 1
Measure B
489
1/03/2018
3
149


District 1
Measure B
486
1/02/2018
2
150


District 1
Measure B
472
1/01/2018
1
151


District 2
Measure A
720
1/04/2024
76
152


District 2
Measure A
775
1/03/2024
75
153


District 2
Measure A
854
1/02/2024
74
154


District 2
Measure A
953
1/01/2024
73
155


District 2
Measure A
964
1/12/2023
72
156


District 2
Measure A
896
1/11/2023
71
157


District 2
Measure A
974
1/10/2023
70
158


District 2
Measure A
901
1/09/2023
69
159


District 2
Measure A
808
1/08/2023
68
160


District 2
Measure A
826
1/07/2023
67
161


District 2
Measure A
900
1/06/2023
66
162


District 2
Measure A
826
1/05/2023
65
163


District 2
Measure A
791
1/04/2023
64
164


District 2
Measure A
979
1/03/2023
63
165


District 2
Measure A
928
1/02/2023
62
166


District 2
Measure A
951
1/01/2023
61
167


District 2
Measure A
978
1/12/2022
60
168


District 2
Measure A
926
1/11/2022
59
169


District 2
Measure A
849
1/10/2022
58
170


District 2
Measure A
879
1/09/2022
57
171


District 2
Measure A
920
1/08/2022
56
172


District 2
Measure A
829
1/07/2022
55
173


District 2
Measure A
820
1/06/2022
54
174


District 2
Measure A
837
1/05/2022
53
175


District 2
Measure A
720
1/04/2022
52
176


District 2
Measure A
720
1/03/2022
51
177


District 2
Measure A
749
1/02/2022
50
178


District 2
Measure A
961
1/01/2022
49
179


District 2
Measure A
966
1/12/2021
48
180


District 2
Measure A
914
1/11/2021
47
181


District 2
Measure A
842
1/10/2021
46
182


District 2
Measure A
775
1/09/2021
45
183


District 2
Measure A
757
1/08/2021
44
184


District 2
Measure A
809
1/07/2021
43
185


District 2
Measure A
777
1/06/2021
42
186


District 2
Measure A
827
1/05/2021
41
187


District 2
Measure A
689
1/04/2021
40
188


District 2
Measure A
737
1/03/2021
39
189


District 2
Measure A
829
1/02/2021
38
190


District 2
Measure A
809
1/01/2021
37
191


District 2
Measure A
774
1/12/2020
36
192


District 2
Measure A
728
1/11/2020
35
193


District 2
Measure A
807
1/10/2020
34
194


District 2
Measure A
768
1/09/2020
33
195


District 2
Measure A
752
1/08/2020
32
196


District 2
Measure A
759
1/07/2020
31
197


District 2
Measure A
780
1/06/2020
30
198


District 2
Measure A
688
1/05/2020
29
199


District 2
Measure A
612
1/04/2020
28
200


District 2
Measure A
684
1/03/2020
27
201


District 2
Measure A
743
1/02/2020
26
202


District 2
Measure A
827
1/01/2020
25
203


District 2
Measure A
760
1/12/2019
24
204


District 2
Measure A
835
1/11/2019
23
205


District 2
Measure A
801
1/10/2019
22
206


District 2
Measure A
761
1/09/2019
21
207


District 2
Measure A
671
1/08/2019
20
208


District 2
Measure A
682
1/07/2019
19
209


District 2
Measure A
658
1/06/2019
18
210


District 2
Measure A
667
1/05/2019
17
211


District 2
Measure A
512
1/04/2019
16
212


District 2
Measure A
546
1/03/2019
15
213


District 2
Measure A
558
1/02/2019
14
214


District 2
Measure A
618
1/01/2019
13
215


District 2
Measure A
621
1/12/2018
12
216


District 2
Measure A
542
1/11/2018
11
217


District 2
Measure A
561
1/10/2018
10
218


District 2
Measure A
497
1/09/2018
9
219


District 2
Measure A
475
1/08/2018
8
220


District 2
Measure A
457
1/07/2018
7
221


District 2
Measure A
477
1/06/2018
6
222


District 2
Measure A
454
1/05/2018
5
223


District 2
Measure A
384
1/04/2018
4
224


District 2
Measure A
397
1/03/2018
3
225


District 2
Measure A
430
1/02/2018
2
226


District 2
Measure A
444
1/01/2018
1
227


District 2
Measure B
979
1/04/2024
76
228


District 2
Measure B
1051
1/03/2024
75
229


District 2
Measure B
1133
1/02/2024
74
230


District 2
Measure B
1235
1/01/2024
73
231


District 2
Measure B
1192
1/12/2023
72
232


District 2
Measure B
931
1/11/2023
71
233


District 2
Measure B
1193
1/10/2023
70
234


District 2
Measure B
1310
1/09/2023
69
235


District 2
Measure B
1280
1/08/2023
68
236


District 2
Measure B
1299
1/07/2023
67
237


District 2
Measure B
1207
1/06/2023
66
238


District 2
Measure B
1035
1/05/2023
65
239


District 2
Measure B
1284
1/04/2023
64
240


District 2
Measure B
1461
1/03/2023
63
241


District 2
Measure B
1044
1/02/2023
62
242


District 2
Measure B
1252
1/01/2023
61
243


District 2
Measure B
1153
1/12/2022
60
244


District 2
Measure B
1205
1/11/2022
59
245


District 2
Measure B
1124
1/10/2022
58
246


District 2
Measure B
1063
1/09/2022
57
247


District 2
Measure B
1212
1/08/2022
56
248


District 2
Measure B
1101
1/07/2022
55
249


District 2
Measure B
904
1/06/2022
54
250


District 2
Measure B
975
1/05/2022
53
251


District 2
Measure B
750
1/04/2022
52
252


District 2
Measure B
955
1/03/2022
51
253


District 2
Measure B
844
1/02/2022
50
254


District 2
Measure B
920
1/01/2022
49
255


District 2
Measure B
851
1/12/2021
48
256


District 2
Measure B
757
1/11/2021
47
257


District 2
Measure B
676
1/10/2021
46
258


District 2
Measure B
521
1/09/2021
45
259


District 2
Measure B
660
1/08/2021
44
260


District 2
Measure B
796
1/07/2021
43
261


District 2
Measure B
791
1/06/2021
42
262


District 2
Measure B
866
1/05/2021
41
263


District 2
Measure B
762
1/04/2021
40
264


District 2
Measure B
905
1/03/2021
39
265


District 2
Measure B
789
1/02/2021
38
266


District 2
Measure B
950
1/01/2021
37
267


District 2
Measure B
846
1/12/2020
36
268


District 2
Measure B
872
1/11/2020
35
269


District 2
Measure B
753
1/10/2020
34
270


District 2
Measure B
746
1/09/2020
33
271


District 2
Measure B
782
1/08/2020
32
272


District 2
Measure B
769
1/07/2020
31
273


District 2
Measure B
564
1/06/2020
30
274


District 2
Measure B
371
1/05/2020
29
275


District 2
Measure B
219
1/04/2020
28
276


District 2
Measure B
776
1/03/2020
27
277


District 2
Measure B
993
1/02/2020
26
278


District 2
Measure B
1004
1/01/2020
25
279


District 2
Measure B
860
1/12/2019
24
280


District 2
Measure B
775
1/11/2019
23
281


District 2
Measure B
680
1/10/2019
22
282


District 2
Measure B
660
1/09/2019
21
283


District 2
Measure B
598
1/08/2019
20
284


District 2
Measure B
574
1/07/2019
19
285


District 2
Measure B
552
1/06/2019
18
286


District 2
Measure B
503
1/05/2019
17
287


District 2
Measure B
552
1/04/2019
16
288


District 2
Measure B
547
1/03/2019
15
289


District 2
Measure B
619
1/02/2019
14
290


District 2
Measure B
591
1/01/2019
13
291


District 2
Measure B
479
1/12/2018
12
292


District 2
Measure B
500
1/11/2018
11
293


District 2
Measure B
531
1/10/2018
10
294


District 2
Measure B
495
1/09/2018
9
295


District 2
Measure B
543
1/08/2018
8
296


District 2
Measure B
491
1/07/2018
7
297


District 2
Measure B
505
1/06/2018
6
298


District 2
Measure B
480
1/05/2018
5
299


District 2
Measure B
450
1/04/2018
4
300


District 2
Measure B
487
1/03/2018
3
301


District 2
Measure B
521
1/02/2018
2
302


District 2
Measure B
639
1/01/2018
1
303




Provide a data table as TEXT which can be copy pasted and used as a source with which to help you.

How do I upload a .txt file which I have prepared?

edit your question  using this Markdown Tables Generator to create the Markdown table. After you paste it in, select what you have pasted and then hit ctrl+K to format it as code. You could also upload the file to some public sharing site (eg OneDrive, DropBox, Google Drive) and then edit your question to include the link, but not everyone will download a file from the internet.

Don't add an Index column before you Group.
Assuming your data is sorted Descending, I would

Group by whatever you are grouping by

In the code below, I assumed grouping by District


Within the aggregation:

Add the Index column
Then use List.Range to return the last 36 instances and the 95th percentile value


Since List.Range will return all of the remaining items if that number is less than Count, I added an If statement to return null if there were not 36 entries to calculate. You can remove that if you want something else.


    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"District"}, {
        {"95th Percentile", (t)=> let 
            #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(t,"Index",0,1,Int64.Type),
            #"Add Last 36" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Index","95th Percentile", 
                each if [Index] <= Table.RowCount(t) - 36 then
                        List.Percentile(List.Range(t[Value],[Index],36),0.95) 
                     else null, type number)
                    in 
            #"Add Last 36"
        }}),

